Ubuntu 24 broken X after running nvidia-xconfig
I tried everything I could and can't restore a working X config
X -configure
installed nvidia535 drivers
I have an IdeaPad 5 with Intel Iris embedded graphics and NVIDIA MX350.
Boot ends with a message about disabling IRQ9, but it seems the problem is that it can't find a valid screen due to having dual GPUs. X -configure ends with EE Server terminated with error 2. Closing log file.
I clarify this was a brand new Ubuntu 24.04 install and running that nvidia-xconfig (without installing any specific driver) broke everything badly.
